# Swiping through multiple pages in ios UI Automation

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, ios-ui-automation

working in the ios UI Automation instrument and I am currently stuck. My problem is I am trying to automate a horizontal swipe between pages in javascript and I can't seem to get it to work.

I have tried:

"dragInsideWithOptions"

"flickInsideWithOptions"

"dragToFromDuration"

"flickFromTo"

target.dragFromToForDuration({x:50.00, y:200.00}, {x:300.00, y:200.00});

a problem that keeps occurring is it keeps targeting the top navigation bar when I just want it to target somewhere on the window to actually change to a new page. The only info I saw on the references for UI automation deals with rects() and it seems that everytime i specify {x:, y:}{x:, y:} coordinates it thinks im talking about a toolbar or navigationBar. It is not in a scroll view so I simply cannot scroll "left" or "right." Is there another function I can call that will allow my test to move to a different page?

Answer (score 5):

Try this it will works perfectly for me:

Pseudo code:
1. Identify the cell you want to perform the swipe Gesture on. 
Eg: Perform swipe on a Table View cell.
2. Record the events by tapping at the starting of the cell and the ending of the cell to get the start and end offset.

By looking at recorded tap event you can get the tap offeset when yopu choose tapWithOptions method.

eg: you will get tapWithOptions({tapOffset:{x:1.07, y:0.65}});

Then note down the  offset as start offset. 
eg:  {startOffset:{x:0.03, y:0.44}

Similarly do the above for the end offset from the end tap point.

eg: endOffset:{x:0.81, y:0.50}

Once you get the source and the end offsets on that cell,

1. Use the dragInsideWithOptions method on the above offsets.

dragInsideWithOptions({startOffset:{x:0.03, y:0.44}, endOffset:{x:0.81, y:0.50},duration:1}

Finally it looks something like below:
app.mainWindow().tableViews()["UBSTableView"].cells()[0].dragInsideWithOptions({startOffset:{x:0.03, y:0.44}, endOffset:{x:0.81, y:0.50},duration:1});
                    app.mainWindow().tableViews()["UBSTableView"].cells()[0].buttons()[0].tap();

Hope that helps everyone :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using iOS7 simulator then these method wont work. But these method will perfectly fine on Device. Try to run your code on device. Hope this will help you

Answer (score -1):

Try to update your dragFromToDuration call with timeout value:

```
target.dragFromToForDuration({x:50.00, y:200.00}, {x:300.00, y:200.00}, 3);
```

I hope this will help.

Comment: This will not work.  According to Apple's documentation "The offset comprises a pair of x and y values, each ranging from 0.0 to 1.0."